# Calling a method on state change with <g:select/> in grails

Tags: grails, groovy

how to call a method onchange in  tag in grails. onchange display the product information.

Answer (score 1):

you can use javascript framework to do ajax call to your server, or use formRemote (Grails feature) http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Tags/formRemote.html